# Search Outlook 2016 for fragment

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search, microsoft-outlook-2016

If I enter just word fragment ,for example `look` (or `"look"`), my Outlook 2016 will not find message that contains word Outlook. How to make search according to word fragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlook 2016 will do a partial word search **only if the search sting is at the beginning of the word**. For example, in a word called ‘Terminator’, Outlook 2016 will be able to search the word if the search string is something like ‘Ter’ or Term’, but not 'nator'

If the search sting is in the middle or at the end of a word, Outlook 2016 will not be able to search the word.

To do a partial string search in the middle or at the end of the word, you need to use Advanced Find option (something called 'Contains').

This is the only option in Outlook 2016 to make a partial search:

- Click inside the search box in Outlook 2016.
- Click on Search Tools --> Advanced Find --> Advanced tab.
- Click on Field --> Frequently-used fields --> Subject.
- Select Contains in Condition drop-down box.
- In Value add your search string and click on Add to List.

You may select the search string and click on New Search to execute a partial non-prefix exclusive search.

[Here's the how-to with screenshots](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/1838-outlook-search-partial-word-string.html).

Comment: So strange that Outlook has so poor search. Is it possible search according RegEx?